# Show $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}x\log(x^4+y^2)=0$

Tags: limits

How can I show that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}x\log(x^4+y^2)=0$?

I can't use l'Hôspital, because we we are working in 2D. I also considered:
$\log(x^4+y^2)\leq\log(x^4)$, however, since we're working in an environment about zero, the value of $\log$ will be negative, so we actually get $\vert \log(x^4+y^3)\vert\geq\vert\log(x^4)\vert$, so that doesn't help either. I wouldn't know how to do it otherwise; any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried switching to polar coordinates?

Comment: @πr8 I'm not entirely familiar with that. I know that $r^2=x^2+y^2$, but here it's $x^4+y^2$

Comment: Try taking $x=r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$ and taking $r\to0$ anyways.

Comment: Since you are working in an environment about zero, you have
$$ | \log(x^4 + y^2) | \le |\log(x^4)| $$

Comment: You could also set $y=zx^2$ where $z$ does not necessarily go to $0$, but you get $4x\log x+x\log (1+z^2)$ to analyse.

Comment: @BoltonBailey Oh right, as you can see, I mentioned that in my original post, but I messed up with the inequality sign! Thanks. That is actually the easiest way to go, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use polar coordinates:
\begin{align}
x\log(x^4+y^2)&=r\cos\theta\log(r^4\cos^4\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta) \\
&=r\cos\theta\bigl(\log r^2+\log(r^2\cos^4\theta +\sin^2\theta)\bigr)\\
&=2\cos\theta\, r\log r+r\cos\theta\log(r^2\cos^4\theta +\sin^2\theta).
\end{align}

Comment: Hi - is it clear that $|\log(r^2\cos^4\theta +\sin^2\theta)| \leqslant \log(r^2+1)$? Just because the quantity inside the log of the first term is smaller than one. I certainly agree that $r^2\cos^4\theta +\sin^2\theta \le r^2+1$, it's just that extra step.

Comment: I only posted a sketch. The reader is supposed to fill in details, of course.

Comment: Sure - I don't think the inequality is true though; consider $\theta=0$.

Comment: You're. I went too fast. The upper bound is trickier, but intuitively, it should rely on the fact that s$\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ cannot be zero simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

In polar coordinates, we have $$x\log(x^4+y^2)=r\cos\theta \cdot \log(r^4\cos^4\theta +r^2\sin^2\theta)$$

$$=r\cos\theta[\log r^2+\log(r^2\cos^4\theta+\sin^2\theta)]$$

Some light differentiation allows us to show that $$|\log(r^2\cos^4\theta+\sin^2\theta)| \leqslant \max\left(|\log1|,|\log r^2|,\left| \log\left(\frac{1}{4r^2}-1 \right)\right|\right)=|\log r^2|$$

by considering critical points. Our function is thus bounded by

$$r[|\log r^2|+|\log r^2|]=4r|\log r|$$

Showing that this tends to $0$ as $r\to0$ is a simple exercise (in e.g. l'Hopital's rule).